# LEFT JOIN model codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, left-join

I want get field on msph_pl from ms_prod_harga 
this is my model promo

is this correct ?

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('md_promo');                
    $this->db->join('ms_promo','mspr_no = mdpr_mspd_no','left');
    $this->db->join('ms_produk','mspd_no = mspr_no','left');
    $this->db->join('ms_prod_harga', 'mspr_no = msph_no','left');   

     $this->db->where('mdpr_no',$mspr_no);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables looks like this:

(table) md_promo
(value) mspr_no

(table) ms_produk
(value) mspd_no

(table) ms_prod_harga
(value) msph_no

And if you need to join result on msph_pl (value) from ms_prod_harga (table), then this code should work:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('md_promo');
$this->db->join('ms_prod_harga', 'md_promo.mspr_no = ms_prod_harga.msph_no', 'left');
$this->db->join('ms_produk', 'md_promo.mspr_no = ms_produk.mspd_no', 'left');

$query = $this->db->get();
echo "<pre>" . var_export($query->result_array(), true) . "</pre>"; // display the result_array in elegant form
```

Hope that helps, though, it may be not what you really need..

Comment: if this is answering your question you can confirm this